# Google Calender API with JavaScript not working for Port 80

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I tried to use Google Calendar API with Javascript, provided by a local Apache webserver.
Google provides a sample, which should work out of the box:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

Unfortunately, this sample works only, if I run my webserver on Port 8000, but not on Port 80.
If I run the webserver on Port 80, somewhere in the api.js from Google it throws an undefined exception, which I cannot catch or get any details on.

My OAuth Client ID is restricted to **localhost:8000, localhost, localhost:80**. Always with http:// in front of it.

[Here is a screenshot of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbuCr.png) At the top, webserver runs on Port 8000 and it works fine. At the bottom, Webserver runs on Port 80 and it does not.

I did not modify the sample of Google, only inserted my Client ID. I am using Apache on Debian.
Does anyone have any ideas on that?

Comment: Did you copy the entire sample and replace <YOUR_CLIENT_ID> with the key from the API console. The screenshot hint that you have a JS problem "Uncaught exception [object...". Use the debuggin tools in chrome and break on all JS exceptions to find where it occur

Comment: Yes, I did replace this Tag my with Client ID.
Unfortunately, I can set a break point there, but since the google API is obfuscated, it does not help me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't change any part of the code, the resolution I would suggest for your problem is to stay away from ports below 1024 as this [opens up all kinds of security vulnerabilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24598/how-can-i-start-the-python-simplehttpserver-on-port-80). Use 4 digits ports: 8888,9999,4567,etc and you should be fine. Also, I'm assuming you've specified the ports in your clientID uri_origin in Google Dev console.

Comment: But since I want to use this on a website I need to run it on Port 80. Any other port is very uncommon. I provide it via Apache2, so the problem with the python webserver does not affect me, beside that I am aware of most of the vulnerabilities. I didnt specify port 8000 in die ClientID, but rather allowed port 80 as well.